# Couldn't perform atomic initialization SQLite error with Subversion on Eclipse

Tags: subversion, eclipse, sqlite

I'm trying to check out some code from my company's svn repository and I get this message on the console:

```
checkout https://svn.[company]/[repo]/Trunk/[project] -r HEAD \
   --depth=infinity --force
Couldn't perform atomic initialization
svn: Couldn't perform atomic initialization SQLite error
svn: SQLite compiled for 3.7.14.1, but running with 3.7.4
```

But, on the terminal, I can checkout the project without problems.

Has anyone been able to solve this problem as well?

I'm running Slackware64-current. Subversion is 1.7.8. SQLite is 3.7.14.1. On Eclipse I installed Subclipse from Eclipse Market, which (I believe) is currently at version 1.8.18, here's its about page:

[image: about eclipse - subversion client]

Comment: What distribution are you running? What version(s) of svn and libsqlite3 do you have installed? Is Eclipse bringing its own svn or libsqlite?

Comment: I'm running Slackware64-current. Subversion is 1.7.8. SQLite is 3.7.14.1. On Eclipse I installed Subclipse from Eclipse Market, which (I believe) is currently at version 1.8.18 (will try to edit the original question to add the accordingly 'About Eclipse Features' image.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm using gentoo and got the save error. But after updating dev-vcs/subversion, dev-db/sqlite and rebuild linked apps by revdep-rebuild --library libsqlite3.so all became good.

Answer (score 0):

I experienced this problem after installing JBoss Tools in eclipse.  Now neither subclipse not subversive work, failing with the same error you have (though I'm on slackware64-13.37 and sqlite 3.7.5).  I suspect the solution is to downgrade to sqlite 3.7.4.  Fortunately slackware makes that rather simple with the slackbuild scripts.  Do you have JBoss Tools installed?  Subclipse worked fine before I installed that.

Comment: Thanks for the input. I'll check that out and will let you know the result.